# How do I chain a task to another task without knowing the first task's result type

Tags: generics, reflection, expression-trees, task-parallel-library

Suppose I have an API that returns a Task as an object:

```
    private static object CreateTask()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "Task string");
    }
```

I need to extend the API with a function that returns another Task chained to the Task returned by CreateTask function so that the new Task's result would be the result of the initial Task. I.e. something like this:

```
    private static object WrapTask(dynamic task)
    {
        object new_task = task.ContinueWith(parentTask => parentTask.Result, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

        return new_task;
    }
```

The usage sample:

```
        var task = (Task<string>)WrapTask(CreateTask());

        Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

is supposed to print "Task string" string.

The problem with the WrapTask function is that the compiler refuses to accept this construction:

```
        object result = task.ContinueWith(parentTask => parentTask.Result, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

with the following error:

```
        Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

Would appreciate any ideas on how to go about extending the API in the described way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dynamic typing to call a generic method with type inference provided by the dynamic typing:

```
private static object WrapTask(dynamic task)
{
    return WrapTaskImpl(task);
}

private static Task<T> WrapTaskImpl<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(parentTask => parentTask.Result,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}
```

It's not at all clear what the point of this wrapping is, mind you... nor why you'd want to just cast the *result* of `WrapTask` - if you know that it's a Task, why don't you cast the result of `CreateTask` instead, at which point you can call `WrapTask` simply? Or maybe make `WrapTask` perform the casting itself?

```
private static Task<T> WrapTask<T>(object task)
{
    Task<T> realTask = (Task<T>) task;
    return realTask.ContinueWith(parentTask => parentTask.Result, 
                                 TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}
```

Then your calling code becomes

```
var task = WrapTask<string>(CreateTask());

Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

Comment: The API above is a simplification. The real situation in a nutshell: There is an API (a group of methods) returning Task<TResult>. TResult may be different for every method. I need to design a solution that would allow to log calls to an object implementing that API. I figured that this was a job for an aspect. To hook up that aspect I use Unity's interception. So, the interceptor creates a continuation on the original Task<TResult> returned by the API. In this continuation implemented the logging aspect. Then the interceptor should return what the calling site expects Task<TResult>

Comment: Where TResult is the actual result of the original task. Why 'object' you asked.. This is because in the interceptor the result is available thru an instance of IMethodReturn.ReturnValue which is 'object'.. Or I'm still missing something?

Comment: @ay.metallo: Right - that makes more sense. When you present what looks like a pointless task, it's always explaining why it's not *really* pointless.

Comment: BTW thanks for the elegant solution (I've always known that it's just bound to be something simple; dynamics are powerful indeed)! It seems to work okay.

Comment: @ay.metallo: So which solution are you using? If you can use the latter, I would...

Comment: I can't seem to use the latter: the WrapTask has to be able to wrap a generic Task<TResult> where TResult is not known till the runtime. So, I'm with the dynamic-based code :)

Comment: @ay.metallo: Ah - your sample code knew the "string" part at compile-time, which was what confused me.

Comment: Sorry again for that :) Just was trying to keep it simple for the sake of example.. Need to be more careful next time.

Comment: @ay.metallo: No problem. It can be difficult to know how much to include, I realise :)